# convert C# System.Unit16[,] to Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I receive data from a .dll written in C# which generates a 2D array of type System.Uint16[,]
I need to convert this data in python to a list as quick as possible, to publish it on Ros2. That is the only format supported by Ros python.

I have tried a few things:

```
Data_RawADC = list(Res)
Data_RawADC = np.reshape(Data_RawADC, (4, int(len(Data_RawADC)/4)))
```

This works but takes very long time.
I also tried this:

```
Res_iter = list(np.fromiter(Res, np.int16).reshape(4, -1))
```

Also works, but only 12% faster. Still super slow.
Does anybody know a (much) faster way ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I seem to understand you need to do this in python ? If so, you might want to remove the C# tag, as this is used to identify questions where you ask about code written in C#. Tbh, I think I'd only keep the python tag.

Comment: Now, and more related to your question, how would you like your data organized? Since you want to flatten a two-dimensional array to a one-dimensional list?

Comment: _"Does anybody know a (much) faster way ?"_ - Don't use Python. Or don't use a C# data source. Can't you streamline to use _one_ platform, only? Or use an intermediary format that is supported by both languages / platforms? Also: How much quicker do you need (or want) to get? Do you need to speed up the whole process or just this part? Can you make this part superfluent (for example by having some C# code present the data in a more suitable format)?

Comment: @Irwene, I'm a newbie to StackOverflow, tags were not clear to me.
A the end indeed I want 1 single 1D python list.

Comment: @Fildor. It's not that simple, there is much more behind... ROS2 only supports Python or C++. All my code runs nicely in python. I started converting to C++ to speed up but there are many issues:
1) At the end I'd like to run on Linux machine
2) The data is coming from an FPGA board, connected thru ethernet, sending UDP frames. I have a .dll file that was written in C# and compiled for windows that handles all the interactions with the FPGA. So much much more that just getting the data.

Comment: Converting the whole C# code to a pure C++ code on Linux is a 3-6 months effort.... forget it. I tried to import the .dll in C++ code, complete fail, both on Windows and Linux. Some people ask me too "why would you want to do this?"...
Today the python conversion takes 0.48s with list() and 0.4s with np.fromiter. I'd like to go below 0.1s, just for the conversion part, which is the botttleneck of my code.
Modifying the C# sharp is also an option, but I will consider only if python fails.

Comment: Wow, that's a tough one. I think I would approach it from the C# side. Mainly because that's my background. But I also think you would benefit the most if data would "come in" as required already.

Comment: Modifying the C# sharp code to output a format that is directly understood in Python as a list would be great, and probably super fast. Any idea how that can be done ?

Comment: I actually modified teh C# code to do the conversion to List in C#, it's not that complicated, using .AddRange.
Yet it remains slow. Anybody knows the fastest way?

Comment: I managed to convert all my data in C# to a single list, by concatenating all lists. Now it works relatively fast: 250ms to capture one dataset. The remaining point is: from my python code, when I call the function in the dll that collects the data, I measure the duration inside the C# code and I see around 250ms. But if I measure the time it takes in python (I only call the dll function, that's all) well it takes 650ms.... Huge overhaed to do nothing. Any idea where this time may come from and how to reduce it? Thanks